# TypeScript: Declare Intersection Type with Symbol?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am currently writing a helper function, that adds a Symbol to a value.

```js
function setSymbol<S extends symbol, T>(symbol: S, on: T, withValue: any = true): S & T { /*...*/ }
```

My problem here is, that I try to explain TypeScript that the result of this function is a value having the symbol-property, so I can do:

```js
const MySymbol = Symbol();
const value = {};

const resultWithSymbol = setSymbol(MySymbol, value);

resultWithSymbol[MySymbol] = true;
```

Is this possible? I played a bit with `unique symbol` but could not get it working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please note that your question title says "type union" but I see no [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), only an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).  Could you please edit the title to better reflect what you mean?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, sure I do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any key type `K` and want to represent an object with that key and a value of type `V`, you can use the built-in [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) like this:

```
function setSymbol<S extends symbol, T>(
  symbol: S, 
  on: T, 
  withValue: any = true
): Record<S, any> & T { 
    return null! // impl here
}
```

(You should determine from your use case whether `Record<S, any>` is good enough or if you want `withValue` to further narrow the type).  Note that `Record<S, any>` is the same as the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{[K in S]: any}` if you want to use that instead. You'll see that your example code works now:

```
const MySymbol = Symbol();
const value = {};
const resultWithSymbol = setSymbol(MySymbol, value);
resultWithSymbol[MySymbol] = true; // okay now
resultWithSymbol[Symbol("some other symbol")] = true; // error
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQMoE8C2AjOAGwB4NFUAPKVMAE2RVwMIBpEAVAPgApkmiAXIgxsEQ9mwDuMKAAsAagENCIVEMVgsiALyIoAJ1UBKIQCVUEOPtqk2GrJ0QAyDogDeAKETfE+9CH0kMBBCQgBCDwBfLw9LMGQoRABZLGx8Ih1hfkJuIwBuWIQExAA3ZVVMt0iCuOK-ZBCoAHUZWTTmTLRMbO4U9qI2MpVUfI96xpa5fsIAbT7sgF1Mg1U8xAB6dcQ4AGtFLTA4STHUBsJm1umZ6e4AImQ4HFRtuVR9RnTCW6Ml3RXUNabcj6fRWDxAA)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed :)